# por que al intentar añadir datos nuevos en un archivo json, el programa elimina el objeto anterior y re-asigna todo?

Tags: python-3.x, json

```
import json

def crear_usuario():
    balance=100000
    data={}

    print("Nuevo? Tranquilo! Sigue las instrucciones y crearas una cuenta con nosotros.")
    nombrePersona=input("Escribe tu nombre completo: ")
    usuario=input("Escribe el nmbre de usuario con el cual deseas iniciar sesion: ")
    pinUsuario=input("Escribe tu pin.")

    data[usuario]={'pin':pinUsuario,'nombrepersona':nombrePersona,'balance':balance} 
   
    with open('datos_usuarios.json','w') as files:
        json.dump(data,files, indent=2)
        files.close()

crear_usuario()
```

Lo que intento es almacenar datos en un archivo json, la primera vez funciona, pero mi propósito es que cuando el usuario llame a esta función el programa no reasigne los datos en el archivo json, lo que quiero es añadir los nuevos datos... Ando un poco perdido.

Comment: Hola Ezequiel. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir un ejemplo de lo que has intentado? De esta forma la comunidad podrá ayudarte. El enlace con el código es privado. También podrías escribirlo en tu pregunta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en los permisos con los que abres el archivo, verás que el permiso `w` crea un nuevo archivo (si ya existe) y empieza su escritura desde cero.

[Según la documentación de Python:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

> 'w': open for writing, truncating the file first

Si lo que intentas es añadir contenido al .json, puedes usar el permizo `a` que abre al archivo **ya existente** y añade el contenido. Osea, empieza su escritura al final del archivo.

```
with open('datos_usuarios.json','a') as files:
    json.dump(data,files, indent=2)
    files.close()
```

Puedes consultar la lista entera de modos de abrir archivos con `open()` [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Espero te haya servido, saludos.